# How to loop through a folder of CSV files in R

Tags: r, file, loops, csv

I have a folder containing a bunch of CSV files that are titled "yob1980", "yob1981", "yob1982" etc.

I have to use a for loop to go through each file and put its contents into a data frame - the columns in the data frame should be "1980", "1981", "1982" etc

Here is what I have:

```
file_list <- list.files()

temp = list.files(pattern="*.txt")
babynames <- do.call(rbind,lapply(temp,read.csv, FALSE))

names(babynames) <- c("Name", "Gender", "Count")
```

I feel like I need a for loop, but I'm not sure how to loop through the files. Anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are CSV files one column files with no headers? And do they correspond to same record ids?

Comment: What you have already perform a loop through all the files (`lapply` executes an implicit `for` loop across all the files). And you are already producing a single data frame (`do.call(rbind, ....)`). What is the question?

Comment: @Parfait the CSV files have no headers and there are three columns inside which contain a name, gender, and count of that name

Comment: @MichaelGriffiths I'm trying to add a column to the dataframe that includes the year that the name corresponds to.

Comment: What is `file_list` for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My favourite way to do this is using `ldply` from the `plyr` package. It has the advantage of returning a dataframe, so you don't need to do the rbind step afterwards:

```
library( plyr )
babynames <- ldply( .data = list.files(pattern="*.txt"),
                    .fun = read.csv,
                    header = FALSE,
                    col.names=c("Name", "Gender", "Count") )
```

As an added benefit, you can multi-thread the import very easily, making importing large multi-file datasets quite a bit faster:

```
library( plyr )
library( doMC )
registerDoMC( cores = 4 )
babynames <- ldply( .data = list.files(pattern="*.txt"),
                    .fun = read.csv,
                    header = FALSE,
                    col.names=c("Name", "Gender", "Count"),
                    .parallel = TRUE )
```

Changing the above slightly to include a `Year` column in the resulting data frame, you can create a function first, then execute that function within `ldply` in the same way you would execute `read.csv`

```
readFun <- function( filename ) {

    # read in the data
    data <- read.csv( filename, 
                      header = FALSE, 
                      col.names = c( "Name", "Gender", "Count" ) )

    # add a "Year" column by removing both "yob" and ".txt" from file name
    data$Year <- gsub( "yob|.txt", "", filename )

    return( data )
}

# execute that function across all files, outputting a data frame
doMC::registerDoMC( cores = 4 )
babynames <- plyr::ldply( .data = list.files(pattern="*.txt"),
                          .fun = readFun,
                          .parallel = TRUE )
```

This will give you your data in a concise and tidy way, which is how I'd recommend moving forward from here. While it is possible to then separate each year's data into it's own column, it's likely not the best way to go.

Note: depending on your preference, it may be a good idea to convert the `Year` column to say, `integer` class. But that's up to you.

Comment: This way makes a dataframe instead of a list - I was having trouble converting Michael's method from a list to a dataframe. However how would I go about adding the years in a new column to my dataframe? Sort of like appending in python

Comment: Did you include the last line `rbind` of @Michael Griffiths' method? That should do the conversion to a data frame.

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't sound like an `append`, rather a new column for each file. For most datasets, that's not a good idea. Are your `name` and `gender` columns the same for every file?

Comment: `doMC` didn't work for me but `doFuture::registerDoFuture(); future::plan("multisession", workers = 8)` did.

Answer (score 4):

Using purrr

```
library(tidyverse)

files <- list.files(path = "./data/", pattern = "*.csv")

df <- files %>% 
    map(function(x) {
        read.csv(paste0("./data/", x))
    }) %>%
    reduce(rbind)
```

Answer (score 2):

A `for` loop might be more appropriate than `lapply` in this case.

```
file_list = list.files(pattern="*.txt")
data_list <- vector("list", "length" = length(file.list))

for (i in seq_along(file_list)) {
    filename = file_list[[i]]

    # Read data in
    df <- read.csv(filename, header = FALSE, col.names = c("Name", "Gender", "Count"))

    # Extract year from filename
    year = gsub("yob", "", filename)
    df[["Filename"]] = year

    # Add year to data_list
    data_list[[i]] <- df
}

babynames <- do.call(rbind, data_list)
```

Comment: I changed 

# Extract year from filename
    year = gsub("yob", "", filename)
    df[["Filename"]] = year

to manually increment the year because the .txt was trailing but thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Consider an anonymous function within an `lapply()`:

```
files = list.files(pattern="*.txt")

dfList <- lapply(files, function(i) {
     df <- read.csv(i, header=FALSE, col.names=c("Name", "Gender", "Count"))
     df$Year <- gsub("yob", "", i) 
     return(df)
})

finaldf <- do.call(rbind, dflist)
```