# Loop for converting files

Tags: r, loops

I have many files I want to convert from sas7bdat to Rds using R, I am using the following code:

```
name <- read_sas("C:/Users/Desktop/Files/name.sas7bdat")
saveRDS(name, file = "C:/Users/Desktop/RDSfiles/name.Rds")
```

but there are too many files I would like to use a loop to optimize to process, any ideas?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40063507/how-to-loop-through-a-folder-of-csv-files-in-r) can help.

Answer (score 2):

This is simple loop that I would use:

```
path_sas7bdat <- "C:/Users/Desktop/Files/"
path_RDS <- "C:/Users/Desktop/RDSfiles/"

files <- list.files(path_sas7bdat, pattern = "sas7bdat")

for(i in files) {
    saveRDS(read_sas(paste0(path_sas7bdat, i)),
            paste0(path_RDS, gsub("sas7bdat", "RDS", i)))
}
```

PS.: check `saveRDS` option `collapse = FALSE` for speed.

Comment: I'd do the same, but with `file.path` instead of `paste` (and no trailing `/` on folders).

Comment: It seems to work but gives me an error: Evaluation error: cannot allocate vector of size 11.7 Mb.

Comment: @Mee it should be your computer problem, what system is that, how much memory you have?

Comment: 8GB.  for big files gives me that error, any solution?